# overflow scroll won't work on image container

Tags: html, css

I have in my mobile view, 6-7 images to be set to be 100% width of the parent div. They are supposed to be 100% width but about 80% of the parent height. I have set the container to be having overflow scroll but the element doesn't scroll. I have set the height of '.stills' to be 600vh just to check if that was the issue but it still won't scroll.
[image]

HTML

```
<div id="stills" data-tab-content>
            <div class="stills">
               <div class="still-wrapper">
                  <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/MA/stills/1.jpg" alt="still 1">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper">
                  <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/MA/stills/2.jpg" alt="still 2">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper">
                  <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/MA/stills/3.jpg" alt="still 3">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper">
                  <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/MA/stills/4.jpg" alt="still 4">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper">
                  <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/MA/stills/5.jpg" alt="still 5">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper">
                  <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/MA/stills/6.jpg" alt="still 6">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper">
                  <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/MA/stills/7.jpg" alt="still 7">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper">
                  <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/MA/stills/8.jpg" alt="still 8">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

CSS

```
/* MOBILE STYLES */
#stills {
   width:100vw;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: scroll;
}

.stills {
 
   width: 100%;
   height: 600vh;
   flex-direction: column;
   overflow: scroll;
}
.still-wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   /* overflow: scroll; */
}

/* DESKTOP STYLES - ONLY SOME INHERITED WHICH HAVEN'T BEEN OVERIDDEN BY STYLES ABOVE */
#stills {
   width:260vw;
   height: 100vh;
}

.stills {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

}

.still-wrapper {
   width: 80vw;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-img {
   /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
   width: 100% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   transition: 0.3s;
}

.inner-img:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are wanting to do. Is each .still-wrapper supposed to only show 80% of the image, and the other 20% is supposed to scroll?

Comment: i will post an image

Comment: i just to be able to scroll down and see the rest of the images

Comment: So you just want images to stack vertically like a regular site, without scrollbars except for the default browser scrollbar?

Comment: yes exactly, thats why i set the with and height to 100%

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are wanting to do? I'll edit my answer if so, to describe what I changed.

EDIT:
I organized the CSS into desktop/mobile and placed them into media queries, to be clear what needed to be reset. I noticed that the height of `#stills .stills .still-wrapper` was explicitly set in the desktop media query, so I reset that using `height: unset;`.

```css
/* DESKTOP STYLES - ONLY SOME INHERITED WHICH HAVEN'T BEEN OVERIDDEN BY STYLES ABOVE */
#stills {
    width:260vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#stills .stills {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#stills .stills .still-wrapper {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#stills .stills .still-wrapper .inner-img {
    /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#stills .stills .still-wrapper .inner-img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* MOBILE STYLES */
@media(max-width: 768px){
    #stills {
       width:100vw;
       /* height: 100%; */
       overflow: scroll;
    }
    #stills .stills {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       flex-direction: column;
       overflow: scroll;
    }
    #stills .stills .still-wrapper {
       width: 100%;
       height: unset;
       /* overflow-y: scroll; */
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="stills" data-tab-content>
    <div class="stills">
      <div class="still-wrapper">
        <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="https://cdn.avopix.com/photos/detail/d_167104_compass-watch-navigational-instrument.jpg" alt="still 1">
      </div>
      <div class="still-wrapper">
        <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="https://cdn.avopix.com/photos/detail/d_167104_compass-watch-navigational-instrument.jpg" alt="still 1">
      </div>
      <div class="still-wrapper">
        <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="https://cdn.avopix.com/photos/detail/d_167104_compass-watch-navigational-instrument.jpg" alt="still 1">
      </div>
      <div class="still-wrapper">
        <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="https://cdn.avopix.com/photos/detail/d_167104_compass-watch-navigational-instrument.jpg" alt="still 1">
      </div>
      <div class="still-wrapper">
        <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="https://cdn.avopix.com/photos/detail/d_167104_compass-watch-navigational-instrument.jpg" alt="still 1">
      </div>
      <div class="still-wrapper">
        <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="https://cdn.avopix.com/photos/detail/d_167104_compass-watch-navigational-instrument.jpg" alt="still 1">
      </div>
      <div class="still-wrapper">
        <img class="inner-img" loading="lazy" src="https://cdn.avopix.com/photos/detail/d_167104_compass-watch-navigational-instrument.jpg" alt="still 1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: except the flex would just be column